# Wordpress Custom Login Page can't accessible if user is logged in and will be redirect to Account page

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-shortcode

I need help with this case.

How to if a user is logged in are not allowed to access Login page and will be redirected to their Account Page?

I have a WordPress customized login page, and user is logged in still can access by typing /login slug

Here is my code below:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_to_specific_page' );

function redirect_to_specific_page() {

 if ( is_page('login') && is_user_logged_in() ) {

wp_redirect( is_page('account'), 302 ); 
  exit;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idk I have wrong type or something.
I have change the `wp_redirect( is_page('account'), 302 );` with `wp_redirect( 'account', 302 );` and its fixed.
Can anyone explain this?

My revision code below:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_to_specific_page' );

function redirect_to_specific_page() {

 if ( is_page('login') && is_user_logged_in() ) {

wp_redirect( 'account', 302 ); 
  exit;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use it on wp action to redirect.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_to_specific_page' );

function redirect_to_specific_page() {

 if ( is_page('login') && is_user_logged_in() ) {

wp_redirect( 'account', 302 );
  exit;
     }
}
```

Comment: The code still doesn't work with me. But I got fixed by changing the `wp_redirect( is_page('account'), 302 ); ` with `wp_redirect( 'account', 302 );`. Anyway thank you for the answer!